# Issues connecting to YouTube API with Go's net/http package

Tags: go, youtube-api

I think this may be my first question on SO. I've just been immersing myself in Go. I just got done reading *An Introduction to Programming in Go* and I wanted to just write a simple program that would query the YT Data API v3.

The issue: when I execute `go run request.go` I get a `404 Not Found` error. However when I take the URL that's passed and paste in my browser or Postman the request works fine. Here's what my `func main() {}` looks like:

```
func main() {
    // read in API key
    key, error_ := ioutil.ReadFile("user_data.txt")
    if error_ != nil {
        log.Fatal(error_)
    }
    api_key += string(key)

    // buil url
    url := base_url + query + api_key
    // Uncomment the next line to show that I'm not insane.
    // url = "http://ip.jsontest.com/"

    // make request
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    body, error_g := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if error_g != nil {
        fmt.Println(error_g)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp.Status)
    fmt.Println(resp.Request)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    // parse response
    var vs Videos
    err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&vs)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", err)
        // fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, v := range vs.Items {
        fmt.Println(v.Id.VideoId, v.Snippet.Title)
    }
}
```

And here is the link to the program in my repo [request.go](https://github.com/Tuss4/go_book_training/blob/master/request.go)

Comment: I've uncommented the line and got 200 OK from jsontest. Either the code you present is different from the one that doesn't work, or you have something with your network.

Comment: if you have a google developers API key, create a file called `user_data.txt` and paste it in there. Make sure the file is in the same directory as `request.go`. Re-comment the `ip.jsontest.com` line, then try again to see if it will work.

Comment: Unrelated to your question - Google does have an API Client for Youtube written in Go: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/go

Comment: Yeah I did think about using that, however I also wanted to try out `net/http` by itself. I would assume that the Go client also draws from that package at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised your example works, assuming that is the whole thing, as you haven't defined `base_url` or `query` for `url := base_url + query + api_key`. I'd rather leave that as a comment than an answer, but I don't have enough rep to do so.

I'm assuming that you've tried this, but I'd print out your built url and double check it looks something like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7lCDEYXw3mM&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The other thing you should consider using, which might indirectly solve your problem, is the [net/url](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) package to build your URLs. Then you can do something like:

```
params := url.Values{}
params.Add("id", video_id)
params.Add("key", api_key)

url := &url.Url{
    Host: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos',
    Query: params.Encode()
}

get_url := url.String()
```

It's a bit more tedious, but the advantage here is that it takes care of all of the encoding and query building for you. My guess is that this is probably where something is going wrong, assuming you're reading in your API key properly, and it is indeed valid for the Data API. Obviously you'd want to bust that logic out into a function call to make it more reusable, but you get the idea.

Comment: Take a look at [request.go](https://github.com/Tuss4/go_book_training/blob/master/request.go), I will try the `net/url` package however.

Comment: From the docs it looks like you should be getting a `400 Bad Request` if you're formatting your URL wrong. Since you're receiving a 404 it's more likely that there is an issue with your token. Have you followed all of the steps in the API [Intro](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#intro) for setting up your API Key?

Comment: Yup. It works fine when you use a client like POSTMAN or in the browser, even with curl.